# Why are tags "roles" and "user-roles" distinct?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

[roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roles) [user-roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-roles)

Reading info pages for these tags I have feeling they're covering the same topic? Yet they're not synonyms, as far as I can tell.

Should they be merged or am I failing to understand their difference?

Comment: I'm not convinced that they're synonymous.  I *could* be convinced but I'm not seeing anything to lean me to that side.

Comment: @Makoto - the fact that their tag wikis clearly describe the same thing isn't evidence? Is there anything at all to suggest that they *aren't* both describing groups of users that share permissions, as the tag wikis describe? Scrolling through the questions, I can't tell that I'm in one tag versus the other - these seem like clear synonyms to me.

Comment: @SamHanley If that were true, we wouldn't have trouble removing tags by just using "DO NO USE". I prefer using actual usage as metric, which is all over the place.

Comment: @Braiam if what were true? I don't follow what you're saying. Can you try to clarify? I specifically mentioned that I scrolled through the tags to explore their actual usage, which, while not extremely narrow, struck me as being indistinguishable between the two tags.

Comment: @SamHanley "the fact that their **tag wikis** clearly **describe** the same thing isn't evidence" The tag wikis can describe the answer to life, the universe and everything else, but if people uses as how they see fit without following the guidance, then that's what the tags effectively mean, irrespectively of the tag excerpt/wiki.

Comment: There are lots of different roles besides user roles (admin, developer, tester, etc...)

Answer (score -3):

From my experience in development, there are typically lots of different roles defined for a system other than user roles. These roles might include such titles (with the implied responsibilities) as:

- Developer
- Tester
- Administrator
- Read Only

Et cetera.... I've tried to give as generic a list of roles as I can come up with from what I've come across in my my professional life. Many companies will define all sorts of variants to this as applies to their specific requirements.